# How to read the content of files synchronously in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

This is what I have:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs'),
    files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/files/'),

files.forEach(function(file) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/files/' + file, 'utf8', function (error, data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
})
```

Even though I'm using `readdirSync` the output is still asynchronous:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/node/readFiles$ node index.js 
foo 1

foo 3

foo 2
```

How to modify the code so the output becomes synchronous?

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/node/readFiles$ node index.js 
foo 1

foo 2

foo 3
```

Comment: I think your problem is that `forEach` doesn t garantee order, you should try with a dumb for loop. Also, you should use readFileSync if you want to read files syncronously

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need to use `readFileSync`, your method is still reading the files asynchronously, which can result in printing the contents out of order depending on when the callback happens for each read.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/files/');

files.forEach(function(file) {
  var contents = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/files/' + file, 'utf8');
  console.log(contents);
})
```

Answer (score 7):

That's because you read the file asynchronously. Try:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs'),
    files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/files/'),

files.forEach(function(file) {
  var data = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/files/' + file, 'utf8');
  console.log(data);
});
```

[NodeJS Documentation for 'fs.readFileSync()'](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options)

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [`readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options)? I think that could be your new friend.