# Read two file and print browser

Tags: javascript

There are two files in the form `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`.
`file1.txt` contains string `Hello` and `file2.txt` contains string `World!`.
I read these files in order and read `Hello World!`. I want to print this in a browser. I could not test with pipe. Could you help?

Comment: Read them from where? local disk or server? In what environment browser or other? Please take a few minutes to read through [ask] as well as [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I keep the data on disk and I want to print it to the browser.

Comment: These articles might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135302/how-to-read-the-content-of-files-synchronously-in-node-js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448336/reading-and-returning-multiple-files-in-node-js-using-fs-readfile